# $m^2+n^2$ and $m^2-n^2$ cannot both be squares

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, square-numbers, sums-of-squares

I need to show that there aren't any $m$ and $n$ such that $m^2+n^2$ and $m^2-n^2$ are both squares.

First of all, assume without loss of generality that $m$ and $n$ are co-prime, since otherwise we can divide through by the gcd and get a new pair. Since mod 4 all squares are 0 or 1, the only common solution to both $m^2+n^2$ and $m^2-n^2$ being squares is $m^2\equiv 1$ and $n^2\equiv 0$, so $m$ is odd and $n$ is even.

It also follows easily that $m+n$ and $m-n$ are co-prime:
(EDIT: if $p$ divides both of them, then it divides their sum and difference, $2m$ and $2n$, but $p$ is not 2 since $m+n$ is odd, so $p$ divides $m$ and $n$, a contradiction.)
Since $m^2-n^2=(m+n)(m-n)$ is a square, both $m+n$ and $m-n$ must be co-prime odd squares.

It seems like I have managed to draw a lot of very strong conclusions from this, but I still can't find any contradictions. Any ideas?

Comment: This already asked [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1246469/proving-that-the-sum-and-difference-of-two-squares-not-equal-to-zero-cant-bot)

Comment: How did you get $m+n $ and $m-n $ are coprime?

Comment: You should note that the difference between two squares is odd, i.e., for $n^2$, $n=1,2,3,\cdots$ we have $\{n^2\}=\{1,4,9,16,25,36,\cdots\}$ the difference is $\{3,5,7,9,11,\cdots\}$.

Comment: @mwomath Those are the differences between **adjacent squares**.  What does that have anything to do with the current problem?  Nowhere does it mention anything about the squares being adjacent and so your point is moot.  $4^2-2^2$ is not odd, neither is $7^2-3^2$ or infinitely many other differences of squares.

Comment: in my mentioned case and in your case which is appreciated the result is not complete square, the square root will be irrational in this case